# Is Firebase domain.web.app is ignore by google robots?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, browser, robots.txt

I have 2 SPA in react and 1 static website deployed on **Firebase**.

I wrote in the browser `site: domain.web.app` and my site didn't appear.

If I have to add custom domain to fix this?

One of my SPA was checked with **PageSpeed Insights** and had 96 mobile rank, 100 SEO. **After feew mounths** google don't show it.

Comment: It's not your domain, it's Google.  You can't assume that it immediately indexes any website, including those deployed using Firebase.  There are other tools for managing your sites index with Google.

Comment: It's been a few months for one SPA.

Comment: Unless Google finds and follows an external link to it, or you use the search console to tell it to index, it will never index a site. If you're having problems with the search console, contact Google directly about it.  Stack Overflow won't be able to help you.